# Booting from copy of Linux directory structure

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware

I have a folder containing the folder structure of a Linux machine from `/`. Is there anyway that I can boot from that folder? Ideally I would create a vmdk so I can get a virtual machine out of it. The ultimate goal is to boot up a VM using those files.

Comment: I think you would need to copy the files into some virtual drive container. That might be doable by booting the system with some live Linux and using `rsync` to put the data onto the virtual drive. You would still need to install some bootloader which you could then do using `chroot` and `update-grub`.

Comment: You could export that directory using NFS and boot the client diskless. Would that work for you?

Comment: @Celada how would I do that from my host machine?

Comment: @MartinUeding I would have to remount the drive as writable right? Doesn't the live cd mount it drive as read only?

Comment: What about creating a new vm with vmdk, Boot new vm from an linux iso, I prefer PartedMagic_2012_09_12.iso. Partition and format the new vmdk then scp to your host and copy the file system. Reinstall grub.

Comment: @hanleyhansen: That depends on the distribution defaults, I think. But remounting should be possible in any case, yes.

Comment: @jc__ so i managed to get the files onto the vm drive using parted magic. the drive is mounted at `/media/sda/`. how would i go about reinstalling grub there?

Comment: use grub-install from a command line. use the `--boot-directory=DIR `  switch to point to the /media/sda/boot location. You may have to fight with it to do what you want, check out this iso "super_grub_disk_hybrid-1.98s1.iso" attach it to the virtual machine boot to it and choose the check for any os option just to see if it will boot from your new vhd even without grub installed. I am making assumptions that "vmlinuz-3.13.0-83-generic" or something close exist.